# Spring MVC @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning Java and Spring MVC. I found this code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath: com/myname/spring/junit-context.xml" })
```

I understand that com/myname/spring/junit-context.xml is a relative path. 
My questions is: what is it relative TO in the context of a web application?

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to the classpath (that's why it's prefixed with classpath). You can have several folders and jars in your classpath and Spring will search in all of them for the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" })
```

webapp -> WEB-INF -> spring -> ContextConfiguration file name

---

com/myname/spring

com -> myname-> spring-> file name

just folder structure